# NSDictionary with NSDates as keys

Tags: cocoa, nsdate, nsdictionary

Is it possible to have an NSdictionary where the keys are NSDates and also have it writeable/archiveable to disk?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not using property lists, as only string keys are allowed there. You should be able to write it using `NSKeyedArchiver`, but that has the disadvantage of being a more opaque format. Alternatively, you could of course make a copy of the dictionary where you convert the dates to strings.

Comment: NSDictionary doc lists the following types for plist: NSData, NSDate, NSNumber, NSString, NSArray, or NSDictionary.

Comment: Those are permitted value types. Only strings can be used as _keys_.

Comment: @Ahruman: perhaps what you are thinking of is that in key-value coding, the keys must be strings.

Comment: *sigh* _In a property list_, only strings may be used as dictionary keys. In memory, and object which implements `NSCopying` can be used as a key. Is that clear enough?

Comment: You are right. Important distinction. I edited your answer so I could retract the down-vote.

Comment: @Ahruman: I see now... I had been looking at the `NSPropertyListSerialization` reference, which says nothing about the keys needing to be strings.  But the Property List Programming Guide does say that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should work just fine - and NSDate elements are also suitable for plist encoding. Might depend on the value you put in as values, though.

If you experience problems, please update your question with code.