# NSDate as keys for NSDictionary

Tags: cocoa-touch, cocoa, nsdate, nsdictionary, core-foundation

Is it possible to add NSDate as keys and some arrays as it values in a NSDictionary?

I dont have any requirement of writing the dictionary to disk - archiving or unarchiving, just as this guy needs it: [NSDictionary with NSDates as keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354779/nsdictionary-with-nsdates-as-keys)

But, why I want NSDate to be added as keys specifically is so that I can fetch all keys from the dictionary and do some computations like, fetching the dates from within a range.

Whether two objects with same date value share same memory when created?

Is it possible to have NSDate as key? Also, what other problems I might face with this assumption?

Thanks,

Raj

**Edit:**
After posting my question, I just wrote a sample code:

```
NSDateComponents *dateComps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComps setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
[dateComps setDay:1];
[dateComps setMonth:1];
[dateComps setYear:2012];
NSDate *date1 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComps];
NSDate *date2 = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComps];
NSLog(@"Date 1 = %x, Date 2 = %x", date1, date2);
```

Output:

```
Date 1 = 7945610, Date 2 = bd03610
```

But does the key comparison of NSDictionary interpret these 2 NSDate objects as different?

**Another Edit:**

Also, if I should convert NSDate to NSString using NSDateFormatter, I cannot directly check for dates within range. I will have to perform the following steps:

1. Get all NSString array of keys from dictionary
2. Convert them back to array of NSDate
3. Perform predicates and fetch dates within range
4. Again convert back those dates to an array of Strings
5. Now use this string keys to get values from dictionary!

So, is there any better way?

Comment: NSString doesn't behave like that (necessarily) - you can have two different instances with the same contents. Why not create a dictionary with NSDate keys and see what happens?

Comment: Agreed, updated my question based on what you have said and also written down a sample program to confirm this. But string constants do share the memory locations.

Comment: Using `%x` in the format string is just printing out the hex address of the object reference. They are two different objects for the same date!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, `NSDate` objects can be used as keys for `NSDictionary` - any object type can be used as a key provided it supports the `NSCopying` protocol. Keys are compared using `isEqual:` and **not** by pointer value. See the Overview section of the `NSDictionary` documentation for more details.

Comment: I couldn't find any assurance in the official Apple documentation that NSDate actually properly overrides isEqual: to do real date comparison, instead of just inheriting the default behavior from NSObject. Is there an official source for this information?

Comment: @EugeneOsovetsky - an assurance in a language and framework without a specification? Hmmm... Seriously it is implicit. NSDate implements the `NSObject` protocol, and that requires `isEqual:` which "defines what it means for instances to be equal". Now any class could choose to accept `NSObject`'s implementation, but if the class supports distinct instances with the same semantic value it simply wouldn't work with the framework. For example, `NSSet` relies on `isEqual:`. So while you may not find a statement that `isEqual:` is overridden for a particular class, such as `NSDate`, it is implicit.