# NSDictionary is not setting a value

Tags: objective-c

I am getting a nil value for dictionary.
I am sure there is something stupid here that i can't find.
The user default at the first time is nil, maybe this is the thing ?

```
 NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
     //read
    NSMutableDictionary *dic=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dic=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"list"];
    [dic setObject:dataToSave forKey:date];
    NSLog(@"%@",dic);//show nil where "dataToSave" is not nil.
```

Comment: how are you populating `dataToSave`?

Comment: Why do you alloc/init a `NSMutableDictionary` just to throw it away when you assign the `list` value from `NSUserDefaults` to `dic`?

Comment: Is there actually a value in `NSUserDefaults` for `@"list"`?

Comment: data to save is NSMutableArray of NSMutableDictionaries , and i allocated it just to check and to be sure.

Comment: @maddy - as i wrote there is no value there in the first time . so if i drop this line it does work, i don't know why. also , if i am trying to save back this dictionary to the default it crashes. why ?

Comment: If there is no value in `NSUserDefaults` for the `list` key then `dic` will be `nil`. So setting trying to add `dateToSave` does nothing and you log `nil`.

Comment: One other problem. You MUST use `NSString` keys to put the dictionary into `NSUserDefaults`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initializing the `dic` var with a new dictionary and then right afterwards re-initializing it with the `NSUserDefaults` entry, which I guess is nil.

```
NSDate *date=[NSDate date];
//read
NSMutableDictionary *dic = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:@"list"].mutableCopy;
if(!dic)
{
    dic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
[dic setObject:dataToSave forKey:date];

// if you want to save back to NSUserDefaults, you will need to do this
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dic forKey:@"list"];
```

**Edit**

As rmaddy pointed out, this won't work because you cannot use non-`NSStrings` as keys in dictionaries you save to `NSUserDefaults`.

In order for this to work, the `date` var needs to be replaced with a string.

**Edit2**

modified answer to allow for `NSMutableDictionary`

Comment: Note - this won't work because `date` is not an `NSString`. All keys must be `NSString` to store the dictionary in `NSUserDefaults`.

Comment: ok thanks, it does work ,but now when i am trying to save that dic to the defaults, it crashes.     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:dic forKey:@"list"];  why is that ?

Comment: maddy this is not right you can save nsdate as a key. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786398/nsdate-as-keys-for-nsdictionary

Comment: @Curnelious I didn't say that dictionaries can't have `NSDate` keys, I said that the keys MUST be `NSString` to save the dictionary to `NSUserDefaults`. Big difference.

Comment: ??? as you can see in the link, you can set NSObject as a key for the dictionary, and if you do ,you probably can also save it to the user default no ?

Comment: this is not a costume class- a costume class can't be saved to the defaults, but an NSObject can . am i wrong ?

Comment: @Curnelious The link doesn't cover putting the dictionary into `NSUserDefaults`. I'm telling you the truth. You can't put the dictionary into `NSUserDefaults` if it has non-string keys (or non-propery list safe values).

Comment: @rmaddy Good catch. I copy pasted that bit and forgot all about it.

Comment: @maddy ,it some how still crashes even if i set a string. it crashes when i am saving it, with no message..

Comment: @Curnelious What is the error you are receiving and on what line?

Comment: There's another bug here: you cannot safely treat the return value of NSUserDefaults methods as mutable. It will behave in bizarre ways (ignoring -setObject:forKey: mysteriously) on some systems, and crash outright on newer ones like Mavericks. You must make a mutable copy if you want to mutate something retrieved from NSUserDefaults.

Comment: @Catfish_Man good point. editing my answer now. Also changed it to use `dictionaryForKey:` instead of `objectForKey:` to account for type issues.

Comment: @Dima the error is "Attempt to set a non-property-list object" , but the array is just array of nsdictionaries, when each dictionary is a list of values and keys strings ..

Comment: You can use NSPropertyListSerialization to check if the array is a valid property list object.